# what is probability space

Tags: probability, probability-theory

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability

I was going through the definition  of total probability theorem and came upon this term.Can you guys tell me what it is and how to identify it and it's relation with the theorem.

Comment: Please use proper english, usage of slang as 'u' instead of you is not appreciated.

Comment: Best I can gather from google, the total probability theorem is just a form of the law of total probability, where the relationship comes from the definition of conditional probability: $P(A|B)P(B)=P(A\cap B)$ (which is only a definition when $P(B)$ is nonzero; defining probabilities conditional to probability zero events requires more finesse).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You define a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ by answering three questions:

1. What are the possible outcomes of our "experiment"?
2. How do we group these outcomes into "events" that we can assign probabilities to?
3. How do we calculate the probability of each "event" (i.e., set of outcomes)?

The first question defines the *sample space* ($\Omega$). The second defines the set of events $\mathcal{F}$, also called a *sigma-field* of events. The third will define the *probability measure* ($\mathbb{P}$) that assigns probabilities to each set in $\mathcal{F}$.

$\mathbb{P}$ (in the form of distributions) is what most intro probability courses focus on -- Bernoulli, Binomial, Poisson, Normal, Gamma etc. $\Omega$ is usually pretty obvious (e.g., the outcome of tossing a coin $n$ times) or ignored (e.g., when you talk about a "normally distributed random variable with mean 0, variance 1). $\mathcal{F}$ is a technically difficult area that, for most *applications* of probabiltiy, is not an issue (e.g., we usually care about intervals on the real line or sets of integers...all nicely behaved for the most part).

The only relation with the theorem is that it provides $P()$ in the theorem and defines what types of events you can partition over to get the "total probability".

Answer (score 1):

Loosely speaking, a probability space is a set where all your desired events live. This language is usually used in the measure-theoretic style of probability theory.